# Can someone explain how we can pass template ref dynamically using @ViewChild() decorator in angular

Tags: angular

how we can pass multiple templateRef at same time and received it using @ViewChild() decorator.

Comment: Please show how you are passing single templateRef using `@ViewChild()` now. It could then be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

is it must to receive using viewChild? if not you can send like this;

```
@Input() templateRefs: {
    cellTemplate: TemplateRef<any>,
  }[];
```

in html render like this;

````
<ng-container *ngFor="let cell of templateRefs">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cell.cellTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```
````

Comment: Thanks @TalhaAkca Those are cool ideas that I have already implemented but I want to do this by using `@viewCild` or `@viewChildren`.

Comment: could you please explore  `@Input() templateRefs: {
    cellTemplate: TemplateRef<any>,
  }[];`  how to pass the data for this   @talha

Comment: in the parent component ``` <ng-template #template1>This is the template to send as input </ng-template>   <child-component [templateRefs]=[{"cellTemplate":"template1"}]```. might need slight adjustments but this is the way it works

Comment: its not working for me.
loop will give us template1 with whitespace like `" template1 "` that can't match with <ng-template #template1></template>

Comment: Its not working and showing error msg **TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView**